# "Jumping" at the end of Shemoneh Esrei

Tags: tefilla, minhag, shemoneh-esrei

Some people are accustomed to performing a few little "jumps" at the end of Shemoneh Esrei (after taking the requisite three steps backward and forward) by lifting their heels a number of times. Is there any source for this, or is it an unwarranted extrapolation from the well-established custom of similar "jumping" during Kedushah (mentioned in <strike>Nefesh HaChayim</strike> Rema, [O.C. 125:2](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%91))?

Comment: I wouldn't mind a source for the triple-jump at kedusha.

Comment: Actually, the Rema mentions the minhag for Kedushah in Orach Chaim 125:2 (from Tur and Shibolei Haleket).  The Nefesh HaChayim adds some "flavor" to the minhag by explaining that it symbolizes the connection between our actions and the spiritual world (or something like that - I haven't looked it up recently). In any event I don't remember it being said in the context of "taking shots at Chassidim."

Comment: maybe for emulating the angels? --sorry no source

Comment: The Rema's language doesn't talk about the triple jump.  Most interpret this as "some movement" like raising the feet.  The Eliya Rabbah says that this language (used by the Levush) is a smach for those that jump.  Where is the Nefesh haChayim?

Comment: The triple jump is in the She'lah.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the three times risig up.

Comment: Do you have an exact reference or link to the Shelah?

Comment: Did you mean this one (top of 2nd column)?
http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9736&pgnum=370

Comment: I found the Nefesh HaChayim - it's in Shaar Aleph ch. 11.
See here, about 2/3 of the way down in the first column:
http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34182&st=&pgnum=31

Comment: Ben Ish Hai Parashat Teruma (with Halichot Olam). Zohar Parashat Emor. he Yam Shel Shelomo writes that he observed people jumping and dancing during kedusha, and he calls this practice a “Minhag Burim” (“the custom of fools”). Kaf HaHaim, I believe siman 125 Orah Haim.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no source for this in the classical Seforim, including the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, Mishna Berura, Tur or Rambam.

I have observed many great men in my life and never seen any of them do this.

During Kedusha one does not ***jump***, one "***lifts oneself*** and one's heel" (Kitzur Shulchan Aruch 20:4)

> וכשאומרים קדוש קדוש קדוש, וכן ברוך
>   וימלוך, ***מרים גופו ועקבו למעלה***

Comment: I also saw over Shabbat a booklet with question that Rav Chaim Kanievsky שליט"א was asked. He emphatically stated there is NO SOURCE for this behaviour.

Answer (score 8):

It most likely developed from when someone noticed a Rav or Rosh HaYeshivah coming forward for Kedusha and got back to his place that he *davened* in ust in time for "*kadosh,kadosh,kadosh Hashem Tzivakos*"in which many people have the custom to rise up from their heels for those three words. This person could have erroneously assumed that it was tied to the stepping forward and not to the Kedusha. Just a theory, but I have not heard anything better yet.

Comment: I have seen people perform the "rising on the toes" just after taking the three steps back - before going forward and believe that it is part of the same erroneous assumption.

Comment: Good. And this probably predates the practice of saying the first verse of kedusha along with the chazzan, so the first thing people did after moving forward was bouncing while saying Kadosh etc.

Answer (score 4):

I have heard an answer similar to what Yahu says above: Because one is supposed to stay back until k'dusha (sorry, I have no s'farim here so can't cite that), one steps forward soon before rising on his toes anyway, so people started thinking erroneously that the rising is to be done after stepping forward specifically. I don't remember whom I heard this from, nor any other source information.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes 'minhagim' develop without having a strong reason behind them. I would guess that in this case it has to do with the forward acceleration of the person. When a person finishes moving forward he may have stopped in the final step by just bouncing in place. People may have seen this and copied it also, thus starting the custom. 
Similarly, the recent custom of bowing to each side during "zeh el zeh" probably developed from people swaying.