# Stepping back, forward and bouncing 3 times, after Shmoneh Esrei

Tags: tefilla, women, shemoneh-esrei

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   ["Jumping" at the end of Shemoneh Esrei](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/jumping-at-the-end-of-shemoneh-esrei)

Most questions about Shmoneh Esreh appear written and responded to by men.  So this is asked by and for women who might want to answer the same thing.  According to the other responses, my assumption appears correct, and there is no rhyme no reason for bouncing.

As a female davener, who is very slow, I have never seen what men do at the end of Shmone Esrei.  But my husband assures me that the following is not what men do.

In the women's section, I am puzzled by the actions of some (generally the younger generation), who step back with the appropriate bowing; then forward 3 steps; and then they bounce -- 1 or 3 times -- sort of like קדוש, קדוש, קדוש in the kedusha.  Seeing the younger, halachicly well-educated women, the older ones seem to think the younger ones have learned something that is an improvement and just copy them .

I have asked some rabbis about this, and they are just as puzzled as I am.  I tended to think that perhaps along the way, some woman/women were so slow that they actually ran into kedusha.

No one seems to have an explanation for this behavior, unless it is to develop something sort of "holier than thou."

Comment: "1 or 3 times" - I've also noticed twice

Comment: That is, in fact, what most men do. I don't have any idea how it started or when. I do it and have always assumed everyone else does it, because I picked it up from others around me as a child first learning to Daven.

Comment: I don't think my question was ever fully answered. Yes, raising the heels 3 times.